# Insert Values in the Mysql table

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I am trying to insert the value to the mysql table using php. But I couldn't insert the value using php code. I have attached My table structure and mysql query. can any one please help me to fix this issue.

[image]

**PHP Code**

```
<body>
<?php 
$lahipita=$_POST['pso'];
$hitAd=$_POST['pso1'];
$silumina=$_POST['ph'];
$sunday_observer=$_POST['pl'];
$virakesari=$_POST['p3'];
$thinakaran=$_POST['p4'];
$hitAd_bl=$_POST['ph3'];
$hitAd_bs=$_POST['ph2'];
$sunday_observer_bl=$_POST['p5'];
$sunday_observer_bs=$_POST['p6'];
$words=$_POST['words'];
$payment_method=$_POST['type'];

$total=0;
if($lahipita!=""){
    $total=$total+900;
}
if($hitAd!=""){
    $total=$toal+300;
}
if($silumina!=""){

    $total=$total+500;
}
if($sunday_observer!=""){
    $total=$total+300;
}
if($thinakaran!=""){

    $total=$total+200;

}
if($virakesari!=""){
    $total=$total+600;
}
if($hitAd_bl!=""){

    $total=$total+2750;

}
if($hitAd_bs!=""){
    $total=$total+1650;
}
if($sunday_observer_bl!=""){

    $total=$total+2000;
}
if($sunday_observer_bs!=""){

    $total=$total+1000;
}


$result=iud("INSERT INTO  wp_paperAds(DEFAULT,'$lahipita','$hitAd','$silumina','$sunday_observer','$virakesari','$thinakaran','$hitAd_bl','$hitAd_bs','$sunday_observer_bl','$sunday_observer_bs','$words','','$payment_method','$total')");

?>
```

**Error**

```
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DEFAULT,'','','','','selected','','','','','','dfdfdfd','','Array','600')' at line 1
```

Comment: You should take care of [SQL Injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax error is the lack of the VALUES keyword:

```
INSERT INTO wp_paperAds VALUES (DEFAULT,...)
```

Answer (score 1):

INSERT INTO wo_paperAds (column1, column2, column3) VALUES (value1, value2, value3)

Answer (score 0):

one of the values you are echoing is an array. you need to echo the array item instead

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are missing `VALUES` in your query (`INSERT INTO t1 VALUES ...`).

You can always debug your query like so:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO  wp_paperAds(DEFAULT,'$lahipita','$hitAd','$silumina','$sunday_observer','$virakesari','$thinakaran','$hitAd_bl','$hitAd_bs','$sunday_observer_bl','$sunday_observer_bs','$words','','$payment_method','$total')";

echo $sql;
```

You also need to get in the habit of using a column list.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the VALUES keyword. Try specifying the table rows that you are inserting data into, that way you won't even have to specify DEFAULT. Like this:

```
 $q = "INSERT INTO table (field1,field2) VALUES ('value1', 'value2')";
 $run = mysql_query($q);
```

I always specify table rows because that way I don't have to get the order right in the query, and I don't have to worry about specifying default values. But on a side note, you shouldn't be inserting an array into the database. Also, I would put a space after the table name and before the first ( in the query, it just looks better. :)

Hope that helps.